# Change Text Validation Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to to do the following, any ideas

I have a Products model with two fields, both strings.

Name
Position

I would like on the index pages for the products to display the Name in Red if the Positions field is blank in the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is better style to post what you got and ask about specific problems you run into. Now your question reads like a feature in a spec, try to be specific about what part of the implementation you are unsure of.

Answer (score 1):

Create **`helper`** method to check if **object** is `blank?`

```
def set_css_class(object, css_class)
  " #{css_class}" if object.blank?
end
```

Call it in your **`View`**:

```
<div class="name <%= set_css_class(@poroduct.position, 'red') %>">
  <%= @product.name %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="<%= product.position.nil? ? "red" : "blue" %>">
  <%= product.name %>
</span>
```

Update:

Let's say you have code like you provided in comment, modify it to:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to admin_printer_path(printer), :class => 'ico' do %>
    <b<%= ' class="error"' unless printer.position? %>><%= printer.name %></b>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

and in css file/section in header add (or modify according to your structure):

```
.error { color: red; }
```

Comment: Seems to like not getting any errors if i add this in but not changing the text

Comment: Text color is not changing to Red

Comment: @user1267003 Do you have any code in index file? Care to provide part you have problem with? Do you know how to apply styles/change appearance of elements in html? I provided example how to test for nil value (you can use `blank?` instead of `nil?` if you want to test for empty string too) and then output something in view (add class to element).

Comment: <td> 
       <%=link_to admin_printer_path(printer), :class => 'ico' do%>
        <b><%= printer.name%></b>
        <% end %></td>

Comment: The other field i have in the database is image_file_name (String)

Comment: mmm still not working, i am not getting any errors but it is not displaying the red